# reformating a date on Python

Tags: python, string, join, replace, split

I am trying to solve this sample exercise for a class I am taking, the question is:

```
Define function reformat which replaces all occurrences of "-" with "/" in a string. Once defined, your function should work like this:

new = reformat("29-04-1974")
print(new)
"29/04/1974"
```

I am not too familiar with python but have come up with the following:

```
date = "29", "04", "1974"
new = reformat("29-04-1974")
def reformat(x):
    x = ("%s" "%s" "%s" % date).split("-") 
    return x

p = "/".join(reformat("%s" "%s" "%s" % date))

print (p)
```

This prints: 29041974

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Your code is wrong and pretty in efficient, Why you don't use `str.replace`? :

```
>>> "29-04-1974".replace('-','/')
'29/04/1974'
```

Answer (score 1):

or you could use the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html) functions:

```
from datetime import datetime

dt = datetime.strptime('29-04-1974', '%d-%m-%Y')  # parse the string into 
                                                  # a datetime object
print(dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))                    # format the datetime
```

that will give you a lot of flexibility if you change your mind on how to display the date.

**what is wrong with your function:**

- you are not using (reading) the `x` you want to pass as argument. the function always uses the `date` you have defined beforehand.
- you create a string without `-` but want to split at every `-`.
- `"%s" "%s" "%s" % date` translates to `"%s%s%s" % date` which is the string `29041974` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong:

Your reformat function **never** used x as input.

Also, replace is the simpler and right solution.